# Troubles displaying objects in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm trying to develop a web application, and I got stuck when displaying my data from the controller to the JSP,

*The database connection works
*The controller is also working properly 
*The fact to input data from the JSP form to the database, also works

I beleive there is something wrong, on the JSTL tags or the importing references, please if somebody can help me with will be very appreciated,

**DAO Implementation class**

```
public class ApplicantImplementation implements DAOApplicant {

    Connection connection;

    public ApplicantImplementation() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        connection = Connection_database.get_Connection();
    }
   public Applicant retreiveApplicant(String applicantID) {
        Applicant applicant = null;
        PreparedStatement statement;

        try {
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM APPLICANTS WHERE applicant_id = ? ");

            statement.setString(1, applicantID);

            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                applicant = new Applicant();
                applicant.setApplicantID(result.getString("applicant_id"));
                applicant.setUsername(result.getString("username"));
                applicant.setPassword(result.getString("password"));
                String firstName = result.getString("first_name").substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result.getString("first_name").substring(1).toLowerCase();
                applicant.setFirstName(firstName);
                String lastName = result.getString("last_name").substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result.getString("last_name").substring(1).toLowerCase();
                applicant.setLastName(lastName);
                String profession = result.getString("profession");
                profession = profession.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + profession.substring(1).toLowerCase();
                applicant.setProfession(profession);
                String phoneNumber = result.getString("phone_number");
                phoneNumber = "(" + phoneNumber.substring(0, 3) + ")-" + phoneNumber.substring(3, 6) + "-" + phoneNumber.substring(6, 10);
                applicant.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                String email = result.getString("email").toLowerCase();
                applicant.setEmail(email);
                String streetAddress = result.getString("street_address").substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result.getString("street_address").substring(1).toLowerCase();
                applicant.setStreetAddress(streetAddress);
                String postalCode = result.getString("postal_code");
                postalCode = postalCode.substring(0, 3) + " " + postalCode.substring(3, 6);
                applicant.setPostalCode(postalCode);
                String city = result.getString("city").substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result.getString("city").substring(1).toLowerCase();
                applicant.setCity(city);
                String province = result.getString("province").substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result.getString("province").substring(1).toLowerCase();
                applicant.setProvince(province);
                String country = result.getString("country").substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result.getString("country").substring(1).toLowerCase();
                applicant.setCountry(country);
                applicant.setAboutYou(result.getString("about_you"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return applicant;
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
@WebServlet("/Applicant")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)
public class ApplicantController extends HttpServlet {
private static String APPLICANT_MY_PROFILE = "Applicants_my_profile.jsp";
 public ApplicantController() throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        super();
        applicant_dao = new ApplicantImplementation();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {doPost(request, response);}


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        action = request.getParameter("action");

      if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("my_profile")) {

            applicant_retreive(request,response);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(APPLICANT_MY_PROFILE);
            view.forward(request, response);
        }
public void applicant_retreive (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        String applicantID = request.getParameter("applicant_id");

        request.setAttribute("applicant", applicant_dao.retreiveApplicant(applicantID));
    System.out.println(applicant_dao.retreiveApplicant(applicantID).toString()); //At this level it works, since it is printing the object from the database 

    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <title>Applicants | My Profile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="applicants_styles.css">

</head>
<body>
        <header>
            <nav class="nav_bar">

                <ul class="nav_buttons">
                    <li><a href="Applicant?action=applicant_resume&applicant_id=<c:out value="${applicant.applicantID}"/>">My Resume</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Applicant?action=job_offers">Job Offers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Applicant?action=view_applications&applicant_id=<c:out value="${applicant.applicantID}"/>">My applications</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Applicant?action=my_profile&applicant_id=<c:out value="${applicant.applicantID}"/>">My profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav_greeting">
                    <li>Welcome </li>
                    <li><c:out value="${applicant.firstName}" /></li>
                    <li> | </li>
                    <li><c:out value="${applicant.applicantID}" /></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="main">


                <div class="my_profile">

                    <h1>My Profile</h1>

                    <div class="my_profile_display">


                        <label>Applicant id:</label> <c:out value="${applicant.applicantID}" />

                        <br>

                        <label>Username:</label> <c:out value="${applicant.username}" />

                        <br>

                        <label>Password:</label> *********

                        <br><br>

                        <label>Full name:</label> <c:out value="${applicant.firstName}" /> <c:out value="${applicant.lastName}" />

                        <br>

                        <label>Phone number:</label> <c:out value="${applicant.phoneNumber}" />

                        <br>

                        <label>E-mail:</label> <c:out value="${applicant.email}" />

                        <br><br>

                        <div class="row-buttons">
                        <a class="button" href="Applicant?action=my_profile_edit&applicant_id=<c:out value="${applicant.applicantID}"/>">Edit</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

        </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

**My output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `${requestScope.applicant}` instead of just `${application}`.

If it still doesn't work, you need to give us more information, for example which application server you're using, which version, if you run as a WAR, etc.

Two additional tips:

1. The code has room for improvement. For example, if an `Exception` occurs in `retreiveApplicant()`, it will return `null`, and it will be another exception down the road
2. `<c:out value="${foo}" />` can be replaced with just `${foo}` if you run with a not too old application server

Comment: Thank you very much, also thanks for the tips to improve my project

I have tried substituting the tags, but still it does not display my objects, same case as forEach loops,

I'm running Tomcat 9.0 
on a maven project 
javaee-web-api 8.0
servlet-api 2.5
jstl-api 1.2
jstl 1.2
are my dependencies

Comment: Please check the following project that works https://github.com/nfrankel/jstl-embedded-tomcat

Comment: Why `Try using ${requestScope.applicant} instead of just ${application}` would work? Do you understand how `${application}` works?

Comment: It seems you want to play the downvote game while I'm trying to genuinely help. I'll leave you to it, I've more important things to do. Thanks for giving me a blog post theme to write about.

Comment: @Nicolas - Do not deviate from the topic. I had not gone through your answer; otherwise, I would have downvoted it earlier itself. My question to you is, do you understand the scope of JSTL variables? In this case, it doesn't make sense that `${requestScope.applicant}` would work instead of just `${application}`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with a [minimum verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then add more stuff (e.g. JavaScript, CSS, more HTML etc.) once you succeed with it. Given below is one such example (mostly using your code):

**Applicant.java**

```
package beans;

public class Applicant {
    private String applicantID;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Applicant(String applicantID, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.applicantID = applicantID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getApplicantID() {
        return applicantID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

**ApplicantController.java:**

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import beans.Applicant;

@WebServlet("/Applicant")
public class ApplicantController extends HttpServlet {
    private static String APPLICANT_MY_PROFILE = "applicants_my_profile.jsp";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        applicant_retreive(request, response);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(APPLICANT_MY_PROFILE);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

    public void applicant_retreive(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Applicant applicant = new Applicant("A123", "Harry", "Potter");
        request.setAttribute("applicant", applicant);
    }
}
```

**applicants_my_profile.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Applicant Information</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Applicant ID: <c:out value="${applicant.applicantID}" /><br> 
        First name: <c:out value="${applicant.firstName}" /> <br> 
        Last name: <c:out value="${applicant.lastName}" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Side note:**

Following the convention, move the following line to the top (make it the first line in your JSP):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Currently, you have declared it inside `<head>...</head>`.

Comment: This directive will be processed by the application server during the first access to the page. As long as it's written before tags that use the taglib, it won't change a thing. But I agree that in normal circumstances, it should not be nested in HTML tags.

Comment: Because your answer has nothing to do with the problem that is mentioned.